# Format of "Where am I this Week?"

Tags: discussion, community-event, community, where-am-i-challenge

This thread exists to help us agree on the precise format of the "Where am I this Week" series going forward, and to provide justification for edits made when the format isn't followed.

I suggest the following rules for how we decide this:

1. Positive-voted answers that have been up for a week will have their modifications to this format implemented
2. When two positive-voted answers conflict the higher voted modification will be implemented

---

### Who should post it?

The first person to write in the comments on the latest "Where am I" question, something to the effect of "I'll post the next one". This should be commented **when you are ready to post it** (and when it is time to post it), not days beforehand. So if you see someone wrote that an hour ago for example but it wasn't posted, you should post it.

I personally would like this format both because I don't want the series to rely on any one person (including me) and because I like it being community-run.

### What should the question text be?

---

I was quite fond of the question text that we made for challenge #2. This makes the

Upload a screenshot of a game into an answer. Others will have to guess in the comments not only which game your screenshot is from, but the location within the game that the screenshot depicts.

Once someone correctly guesses your game and location, edit your answer to congratulate the winning guesser!

It is possible for there to be two winners if one person guesses the game but not the location, and a second person later jumps in with the correct location.

Keep track of incorrect guesses by editing your post to list them. This will ensure no one guesses the same thing twice.

If your screenshot features a procedurally-generated environment, please state so next to your screenshot. If this is the case, participants will only have to guess the game, not the location within.

If possible, turn off your HUD while taking the screenshot to make a harder challenge! You can also blur out the HUD, but please don't completely blacken those parts or do any other types of photo edits!

---

### What should the title be?

Where am I this Week? Challenge #**[n]**

### What should the protocol for moving onto the next challenge thread be?

When a later challenge thread has been posted, update the question with the following at the start:

**This "Where am I?" challenge is now over!** Please participate in the newest question tagged [where-am-i-challenge](/questions/tagged/where-am-i-challenge)!

And update the title with the following at the end:

**[Submissions closed; participate in the latest version!]**

### Abbreviation

Screenshot of the Week: SOTW
Where Am I this Week: WhMI

### Theme choices

Make a theme choice question as a hub similar to SOTW. The themes used in WhMI? should be different from SOTW.

### Frequency

Every 2 weeks a new challenge is posted.

### Unsolved challenges

If a challenge is not solved, the answer is not revealed until the challenge 4 weeks after that one is posted, that is, the answer to unsolved challenge x is revealed when challenge x + 2 is posted.

When challenge y is posted, comments will be posted on unsolved challenges y - 2 asking for the answer.

### Comment deletion policy

SE format indicates that comments should be deleted eventually when they no longer add value. On WhMI? a policy will need to be in place to ensure comments are deleted while still keeping record of the guesses:

Comments giving the first instance of a guess should never be deleted.
Comments giving a guess that has already been stated should be deleted.
Comments that do not give a guess are welcome but should be deleted 2 contests later.

Comment: Participation dropped precipitously after the first week -- I'm wondering if it's run too often. Even the screenshot of the week is every two weeks....

Comment: I don't know if that's enough data to base that on and it wasn't precipitous but I am happy for it to be a different  frequency.

Comment: I mean, half the entries didn't even get a single guess in round 2.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I think both were very obscure, and the Moon one was fairly obscure too, but of course it should be fine to post obscure stuff and give more time for it to be solved. I'd be happy for it to even be monthly, but let's see if people post and answer challenges this weekend.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I would agree the timeframe in which these are posted was part of the problem. A 3rd challenge (now deleted) was submitted not even a week after the 2nd challenge was submitted. Submitting challenges too often leaves the previous challenge in the dust, and forgotten about

Comment: Might also be beneficial to create a "Theme" thread, similar to SOTW, to get ideas and rolling list of themes

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 I think that would be a better idea, yeah. And I think that the answer should just be edited when it is clear from discussion what it should be edited to?

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 I moved the format to the question and suggested more clear rules about how we decide to implement modifications. I've upvoted your modifications so that, unless anyone disagrees, we'll update the format for #4. I'll also make an exception for the timing of the next one and not post it until we agree on whether to change the frequency.

Comment: Does the screenshot have to be full-screen? Or can you just crop a portion of the screenshot.

Comment: @Cave Johnson It seems fine to me to do a portion - my picture of the air altar in Runescape wasn't full screen. I say it just needs to show a unique location.

Comment: I haven't forgotten about this. It just seems like people lost interest in this; if it did continue it might need to be changed to have a new series after X correct guesses. But for now I am just leaving it. If anyone else eventually cares enough, obviously this empowers them to put up the next one.

Answer (score 3):

I do have modifications to some of the current stuff:

## Abbreviation

- Screenshot of the Week: **SOTW**
- Where Am I: **WhMI?**

## Question body text

I was quite fond of the question text that we made for challenge #2. This makes the

> Upload a screenshot of a game into an answer. Others will have to guess in the comments not only which game your screenshot is from, but the location within the game that the screenshot depicts.
>
> Once someone correctly guesses your game and location, edit your answer to congratulate the winning guesser!
>
> It is possible for there to be two winners if one person guesses the game but not the location, and a second person later jumps in with the correct location.
>
> Keep track of incorrect guesses by editing your post to list them. This will ensure no one guesses the same thing twice.
>
> If your screenshot features a procedurally-generated environment, please state so next to your screenshot. If this is the case, participants will only have to guess the game, not the location within.
>
> If possible, turn off your HUD while taking the screenshot to make a harder challenge! You can also blur out the HUD, but please don't completely blacken those parts or do any other types of photo edits!

This makes the instructions more concise now that we all get the gist of things. I am open to making the text seem less strict.

## Theme choices

Make a theme choice question as a hub similar to [SOTW](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15029/250180). The themes used in WhMI? should be different from SOTW.

## Frequency

Every 2 weeks a new challenge is posted. 1 week seems too frequent and SOTW is a 2-week challenge too.

## Unsolved challenges

If a challenge is not solved, the answer is not revealed until the challenge 4 weeks after that one is posted, that is, the answer to unsolved challenge *x* is revealed when challenge *x + 2* is posted.

When challenge *y* is posted, comments will be posted on unsolved challenges *y - 2* asking for the answer.

## Comment deletion policy

SE format indicates that comments should be deleted eventually when they no longer add value. On WhMI? a policy will need to be in place to ensure comments are deleted while still keeping record of the guesses:

- Comments giving the first instance of a guess should *never* be deleted.
- Comments giving a guess that has already been stated should be deleted.
- Comments that do not give a guess are welcome but should be deleted 2 contests later.

Comment: Oh sorry I misread your suggestion about how to structure this discussion. Feel free to just edit my question with exactly what you meant, I think it sounds fine.

Comment: In terms of this question text, we disagree on how prescriptive the challenge format needs to be (the extent to which we have to force conventions like keeping track of incorrect guesses and exactly how they can edit the image for example). But this disagreement is exactly why I made this thread, I saw week 2 went in that direction and I figured we should collectively agree how we want it to be. If people want it to be prescriptive, it is not a big deal.

Comment: @JoshuaBizley Yeah, I like a logical structure, but I'm open to editing this to make it more leniant.

Answer (score -1):

The following was the original format. The format has now been moved to the question text.

---

### When should it be posted?

As soon as possible from the next Thursday GMT.

### Who should post it?

The first person to write in the comments on the latest "Where am I" question, something to the effect of "I'll post the next one". This should be commented **when you are ready to post it** (and when it is time to post it), not days beforehand. So if you see someone wrote that an hour ago for example but it wasn't posted, you should post it.

I personally would like this format both because I don't want the series to rely on any one person (including me) and because I like it being community-run.

### What should the question text be?

---

Welcome to the **[nth]** challenge thread in the "Where am I?" series.

A "Where am I?" challenge involves posting a screenshot from a game and having other users guess in the comments what game it is and where in the game you are. If the game supports turning off the HUD, you are welcome to do that to increase the challenge. The content of the screenshot should contain enough identifiable information to ensure there is only one definitive answer. Other than that, you are welcome to use common sense to adjust your challenge's objective while staying within the "Where am I?" theme.

See last week **[insert link here]** for examples.

**Theme**

This is not mandatory but may inspire you to think of a certain environment in some game which would make for a fun challenge. This week's theme is **[insert theme here] (whoever posts the question can decide this)**.

---

### What should the title be?

Where am I this Week? Challenge #**[n]**

### What should the protocol for moving onto the next challenge thread be?

When a later challenge thread has been posted, update the question with the following at the start:

**This "Where am I?" challenge is now over!** Please participate in the newest question tagged [where-am-i-challenge](/questions/tagged/where-am-i-challenge)!

And update the title with the following at the end:

**[Submissions closed; participate in the latest version!]**